# pandas df to dict with groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have this df :

```
line stop
1    1_a 
1    1_b 
1    1_c
2    2_a
2    2_c
```

I want to create the following dict :

`d={1 : {"stops" : "1_a","1_b","1_c"}, 2 : {"stops" : "2_a","2_b","2_c"}}`

Someone knows how to do that with `to_dict` method ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create nested dictionaries filled by lists by [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `apply`, then [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) and last [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
d = df.groupby('line')['stop'].apply(list).to_frame().to_dict('index')
print (d)
{1: {'stop': ['1_a', '1_b', '1_c']}, 2: {'stop': ['2_a', '2_c']}}
```

If need join values by some separator e.g. `,`:

```
d1 = df.groupby('line')['stop'].apply(','.join).to_frame().to_dict('index')
print (d1)
{1: {'stop': '1_a,1_b,1_c'}, 2: {'stop': '2_a,2_c'}}
```

EDIT:

Solution for multiple columns with [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) and omited `to_frame()`:

```
print (df)

   line stop  lat  lon
0     1  1_a    2    2
1     1  1_b    3    1
2     1  1_c    4    3
3     2  2_a    5    6
4     2  2_c    6    6

d = df.groupby('line')[['stop','lat','lon']].agg(list).to_dict('index')
print (d)
{1: {'stop': ['1_a', '1_b', '1_c'], 'lat': [2, 3, 4], 'lon': [2, 1, 3]},
 2: {'stop': ['2_a', '2_c'], 'lat': [5, 6], 'lon': [6, 6]}}
```

Comment: how can i change this to add several columns to nest ? 
`df.groupby('line')[['stop','lat','lon']].apply(list).to_frame().to_dict('index')` will work ?

Comment: @Pi-R - yop, only omit `.to_frame()`

Comment: @Pi-R - and use `.agg` instead `.apply`

Comment: is there a way to add each name of stop as a key in the dict to have :
`{1: {'stop': {'1_a' : {'lat' : 2, 'lon': 2},1_b : {'lat' :3, 'lon': 1}}}`

Comment: @Pi-R - Give me some time, pls

Comment: Take all the time you need ! You answered every time I post here, I don't want to ast too much

Comment: @Pi-R - Can you test `d ={i: g.set_index('stop')[['lat','lon']].to_dict('index') for i, g in df.groupby('line')}` ?

Comment: perfect ! tanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid the `to_dict` part and iterate through the grouping to get your dictionary, since you are not doing any computations :

```
{key: {"stops": ",".join(value.stop.array)}
 for key, value in df.groupby("line")}


{1: {'stops': '1_a,1_b,1_c'}, 2: {'stops': '2_a,2_c'}}
```

Or you could leave the sub values as a list:

```
{key: {"stops": list(value.stop.array)} 
 for key, value in df.groupby("line")}

{1: {'stops': ['1_a', '1_b', '1_c']}, 2: {'stops': ['2_a', '2_c']}}
```